# Managing the output streams of many subprocesses with deadlocks

Tags: pipe, python, process-management, streaming

I have a Python script that does more or less this

```
current_tasks = TaskManager()
MAXPROCS = 8

while len(outstanding_tasks) > 0:
    if len(current_tasks.running) < MAXPROCS:
      current_tasks.addTask(outstanding_tasks.next())
    else:
      current_tasks.wait_for_one_finish()
```

and outstanding_tasks.next() is basically this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen([task], stdout=OUTFILE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

and `current_tasks.wait_for_one_finish()`:

```
waiting = True
while waiting:
    for t in tasks:
        ret = t.poll()
        if ret not None:
            handle_stderr(t)
            waiting = False
            break
```

Fairly straightforward - spawn tasks on-demand until we're running 8 of them at a time, and then block until they finish one at a time before spawning more tasks.

The problem is this:

```
stderr=subprocess.PIPE
```

Each subprocess is writing is stderr to a pipe. If it crashes and it wants to write a big log message or whatever to the pipe, and that message exceeds the size of the pipe buffer, the write() will block. The process won't finish, so my controlling process will never see a return value from `poll()` and go read from its stderr.

There are obviously ways around this:

- redirect stderr from my subprocesses to temporary files
- spawn a Python thread that reads from the stderr file descriptors of all running tasks and buffers them in memory
- have a select() or something in my little ad hoc event loop

But all of that is stuff I have to handle in my application code. What I want to know is: is there some way to get the behaviour of a pipe, but with a nice big elastic buffer, so that the subprocesses can always do a successful write() to their stderr and then exit, without me having to look at it until they're done?

Comment: You can't look at the processes retcode instead of parsing it's stderr (which is generally bad for error control)?

Comment: I'm looking at the retcode to decide whether it failed, but I need the stderr to get the log output and send it off or propagate the error reporting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is: there isn't.

You've already highlighted the workarounds necessary to deal with large data being sent through a subprocess pipe. The "nice big elastic buffer" pipe doesn't exist. This is called out in the [Subprocess Management Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.poll) as a potential source of deadlocks, with the added solution that you can call `proc.communicate()` to read from stderr. The problem in your case is that you can't call `communicate()` on all processes at the same time, and that method blocks until all data is read.

If it were I, I would probably use a `select()` call on all of the `stderr` processes rather than a `proc.poll()` loop.  `select()` can block until any process does something, and when the process exits, it will close the stderr pipe, so you kill two birds with one stone (know when data is written to stderr and know when the process the dies).

Comment: Thanks, a select() loop on stderr is actually perfect for what I'm trying to do - as long as I make sure I don't close stderr in the child processes before they exit.